# Spring Cloud Stream Processor from two different Kafka broker

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I would like to know whether is possible or not to bind two different Kafka broker for the input and output on Spring Cloud Stream.

In other words, I would like my stream to be listening in one Kafka broker and write the output in other Kafka broker.

```
@StreamListener(Processor.INPUT)
@SendTo(Processor.OUTPUT)
public Object handle(String message) {
    // Processor.INPUTbeing bind to one Kafka broker
    // Processor.OUTPUT being bind to another Kafka broker
    // Write the logic here
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, very much, you can! Here's a [multi-binder application](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/tree/master/multibinder-samples/multibinder-two-kafka-clusters) that reads from and writes to 2 different Kafka clusters.

Pay attention to the binder and the channel binding configurations in the [application.yml](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/blob/master/multibinder-samples/multibinder-two-kafka-clusters/src/main/resources/application.yml).

Comment: Updated URL is https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/tree/master/multi-binder-samples/multi-binder-kafka-streams